# C# Async WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

Can someone give me an example of how to use the method begin to display an alert to the User saying Loading ...
With the code below I place the query using the Completed event, use the method as Begin?

```
service.EventosDoDiaCompleted += RecebeEventos;
service.EventosDoDiaAsync();

private void RecebeEventos(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   Dataset ds = service.EventosDoDia();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place simple Textblock or something like this:

```
    service.EventosDoDiaCompleted += RecebeEventos;
    textblock.Text="Loading....";
    service.EventosDoDiaAsync();
    private void RecebeEventos(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        textblock.Text="Loaded";
        Dataset ds = service.EventosDoDia();
    }
```